# Updating state in Redux using Redux toolkit in NextJS based application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make a cart based ecommerce website. I am using Redux and Redux Toolkit to simplify things. I am fairly new to this and my code is not working as expected.

I am trying to dispatch data to state but the state does not update. Redux Devtools show that data is being indeed dispatched to store, but the state remains the same.

[image: Redux Devtools action]

[image: Redux devtools state]

In the action, I am console logging the state items and I think the problem lies here which I can't understand.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

let initialState = [
  {
    name: "",
    id: "",
    quantity: "",
    mode: "",
    bookType: "",
  },
];

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        console.log(item);
        if (item.id !== action.payload.id) {
          return item;
        }

        return {
          ...item,
          added: true,
        };
      });
    },
    remove: (state, action) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id !== action.payload.id) {
          return item;
        }

        return {
          ...item,
          added: false,
        };
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { add, remove } = cartSlice.actions;
export const getCart = (state) => state.cart;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Here is console output:
[image: Console output]

This is how I am dispatching in my code:

```
function formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const requiredCourse = courses[0];
    const dispatchItem = {
      name: requiredCourse.name,
      id: requiredCourse.id,
      quantity: 1,
      mode: mode,
      bookType: bookType,
    };
    if (userLoggedIn) {
      console.assert("About to dispatch");
      dispatch(add(dispatchItem));
      setTimeout(() => {
        Router.push("/cart");
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      openModal();
      setTimeout(() => {
        Router.push({
          pathname: "/user/signup",
          query: {
            redirect: requiredCourse.url,
          },
        });
      }, 6000);
    }
  }
```

Every help is really appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a reducer that adds your action.payload to state.

Comment: Are you using the next-redux-wrapper package? if not -> https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper